# Agregar condición a mi datatable

Tags: php, datatables

Tengo un problema al momento de mostrar en un dataTable una condición de cierta columna.

Quiero que en la columna `opciones`, se cree una condición que si la columna del `codigo_producto` es igual a `0` entonces me muestre el icono de poder eliminar el registro.

Adjunto detalles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me sale el error que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como que no encuentra la columna `1` que es el código del producto.

Adjunto código fuente de las columnas y condición:

```
columnDefs: [{
  targets: 0,
  'data': 'id_caja',
  orderable: false,
  className: 'control',
  visible: true
},
{
  targets: 1,
  'data': 'codigo_producto',
  visible: true
},
{
  targets: 6,
  'data': 'saldo_actual',
  visible: false
},
{
  targets: 7,
  'data': 'opciones',
  render: function (data, type, full, meta, rowData, td, cellData, rowData, row) {
    if (parseInt(rowData[1]) == 0) {
      return "<center>" +
        //opciones eliminar icono
        "<span class='btnEliminarVenta text-danger px-1' style='cursor:pointer;'>" +
        "<i class='fas fa-trash fs-5'></i>" +
        "</span>" +
        "</center>"
    } else {

    }

  }
},
]
```

Comment: Si le quitas el `if` ¿agrega el ícono a todos los renglones?

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo el 3er parámetro de la función `render` sería toda la info de la fila, por lo que la condición debería ser `if (parseInt(full[1]) == 0)` siempre y cuando `full` sea un arreglo y no un objeto.

Comment: Logre que me apareciera el icono de eliminar con la siguiente funcion: render: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) { if (parseFloat(rowData[1]) == 0 ) {, pero me sale el error que "el parametro *opciones* es desconocido"

Comment: Tambien ya intente con if (parseInt(full[1]) == 0) y si me aparece el icono pero siempre me sale la notifiacion que el parametro opciones es desconocido y ya valide que no sea problema de la base de datos. porque efectivamene obtendo el parametro "opciones"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te puede servir lo siguiente condiciono una fila para que se pinte de un color diferente:

```
"columnDefs":[{
            "targets": [0],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "7%"
        },{
            "targets": [1],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "7%"
        },{
            "targets": [2],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "7%"
        },{
            "targets": [3],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "15%"
        },{
            "targets": [4],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "7%"
        },{
            "targets": [5],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "7%"
        },{
            "targets": [6],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "10%"
        },{
            "targets": [7],
            "className": "text-center",
            "width": "7%"
        }],
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData) {
            if (aData.date_payment == dateNow()) {
                $('td', nRow).css('color', '#F44336');
            }
        }
```

Comment: ya intente con if (parseInt(full[1]) == 0) y si me aparece el icono pero siempre me sale la notifiacion que el parametro opciones es desconocido y ya valide que no sea problema de la base de datos. porque efectivamene obtendo el parametro "opciones"

Answer (score 2):

Me hizo falta colocar el `else` a la condición: si no se coloca el `else`, no reconoce toda la tabla y saldrá error:

```
{
    targets: 7,
    'data': 'opciones',
    render: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) { 
        if (parseFloat(rowData[1]) == 0 ) {
            return "<center>" +
              //opciones eliminar icono
              "<span class='btnEliminarVenta text-danger px-1' style='cursor:pointer;'>" +
              "<i class='fas fa-trash fs-5'></i>" +
              "</span>" +
              "</center>"
        }
        else{
            return "<center>" + "-";
        }

    }
},
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.